# Is the term "if you so choose" common?

Tags: meaning

Today I was reading in the Washington Post

"if you so choose"
(https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/arts-and-entertainment/wp/2018/01/01/your-guide-to-2018-movies-minus-the-superheroes-sequels-spin-offs-and-reboots/).

This sounds very strange to me (my mother tongue is german).

My question is:
Is this just a kind of slang expression or is it a normal term?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: It's normal, though formal.

Comment: Common in the sense of being frequently used but definitely not 'common' in the sense of defining the speaker's social class!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google returns over 5 million hits for the expression "*if you so choose*". At the very least, then, we can say that the expression is not uncommon.

Neither is it slang - which can be variously defined as referring to words or expressions that have a limited currency (such as *sick* = *very good*). Or to words generally used only by a particular group of people. In fact, the expression "*if you so choose*" is most likely to be found in formal written prose, as a quick scan of the Google hits will show.

In this context, *so* functions as an *anaphoric* (backward-pointing) or *cataphoric* (forward-pointing) reference to some other part of the sentence. See the two authentic examples from Google below:

> - This person will also coordinate care with specialists, or your home practitioner if you **so** (anaphoric) choose.
> - If you **so** (cataphoric) choose, you can also set aside a custodial IRA, which gets them started very early on saving for retirement.

In other contexts where *so* functions as a reference, it is usually used anaphorically (not cataphorically), and follows the verb rather than preceding it as in "*if you so choose*".

> - Why a safe workplace for women is a myth and will remain **so**!
> - The NFL could have sent that message loud and clear, but failed to do **so** this week with their light punishments for all parties involved.